# What is the correct SE site for a question about sfdisk?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73929913/does-sfdisk-under-linux-have-a-preset-default-for-sector-size) about [sfdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sfdisk). I thought it was about programming, since reformatting or copying data back and forth is often a function of what I do in programming. Apparently it's not, so it's closed.

So, simple version, what SE site is the best place to ask this?

Comment: "*reformatting or copying data back and forth is often a function of what I do in programming*" it's more often something a system administrator would do. Or even just a computer repair shop employee. Or just a power user. Neither of them needs to know any programming to perform these tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought it was about programming, since reformatting or copying data back and forth is often a function of what I do in programming.

It is not a part of the process of writing the code. The question would be on topic if you were *writing a script to automate a process* that includes reformatting a disk, for example. Then you would have a question about that script, which is code (even if it is shell script, Bash etc.). Simply knowing how to use Linux commands is generally not considered code, even though you might include them verbatim in a script.

> what SE site is the best place to ask this?

You presumably want [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). You could also try https://superuser.com.

However, [I would start](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) with `man sfdisk` at the command line, or `linux sfdisk` [in a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+sfdisk).

Comment: Let me try to take part of what you said and rephrase it to see if I get where the line is. If it's in, "What parameters do I need to use to do this from a script?" that's a programming question. But when it's, "What does sfdisk do and how does it handle this?" then that's not an SE question. Would that be a fair way to put it? (And I did check in the man page. Sectors are mentioned but this issue isn't addressed. Tried various searches and didn't get a clear answer.)

Comment: That sounds about right, yes.

Comment: These days [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) are [also online](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk).